# gradle of the flutter app not working in android studio

Tags: flutter, gradle

My flutter app is not able to Run. Everytime I am trying to run the program, I am getting an error that

ould not compile build file '/Users/sushovan/StudioProjects/funds_gopu/android/build.gradle'.

> startup failed:
> General error during semantic analysis: Unsupported class file major version 60

Even I tried to make a new flutter app from scratch (just default with no code editing), that is also not running. Can anyone please let me know what is the issue.

Comment: Hey have you find solution?

Comment: Yes, uninstalling the android studio and reinstalling did the job.